# How to got the process id for the previous application that was on focus

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, linux-kernel

I want to drop some text into a running application my program is running in background when invoked using a global hot-key I want to get the process ID for the application that was on focus.

My OS is Ubuntu and I am using QT with C++. but I intend to do the same thing for windows too. So any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is window manager specific, for linux you may need to do calls into the X library to handle this. different window managers will handle focus differently.

Answer (score 1):

Under windows you could try using GetForegroundWindow to get the HWND of window which the user is currently working with. If that works, you can then use GetWindowThreadProcessId to get process ID of that application.